# Why did my refrigerator fail and then work properly again?

Tags: refrigerator, freezing

I have a frost free fridge-freezer which failed three weeks ago, the fridge would not get down below 12C, although the freezer seemed to get down to -20C or so. The compressor pot would get pretty hot and the condenser was hot down near the compressor but not elsewhere. Switched off and left for a day or so, but same again on restart.

As the unit was quite new, the suppliers offered a rebate on a replacement if it could be verified as a manufacturing fault, so I had an engineer come out to verify the fault, which he did quickly by observing that the wet wall felt loose on one side. He said "The wet wall has blown, it's degassed and it's not repairable". Great, I was able to take advantage of the rebate and have ordered a replacement.

However, I left the fridge switched on after the engineer left, and it has been running perfectly ever since! That's about a week ago. The wet wall regularly frosts up and defrosts itself, and it has been stable at about 5C in that time.

Can anybody suggest a mechanism for why it appears to have resurrected itself? Could just pressing the wet wall back by hand have somehow fixed it? If so what are the chances of it packing up again?

I hate the thought of dumping the old one if it was a temporary glitch which has resolved itself, but I can't be sure that the fault won't return.

Comment: What's the make and model of the equipment?

Comment: I am not sure of the term "wet wall" is this the evaporator coil? make and model would be helpful.

Comment: Read the second half of your last sentence again, and ask yourself how long you want to be wondering about that.

Comment: Sorry, its a Hotpoint RFAA52P. The wet wall as I understand it is the inner lining of the fridge that is in contact with the evaporator coil.

Comment: Was it unplugged for days before the engineer came?  If the coil was significantly frozen it may have taken days to melt, especially closed up.  There may be either a defrost cycle problem or a door gasket problem or both.

Comment: Thanks Tyson, yes it was unplugged for days before the engineer came. Do you think the "wet wall blown" (felt loose) might be a red herring?

Comment: Best guess for "wet wall blown" is "the ice buildup fractured the interior of the box and the adjacent insulation". I think you can be confident that the fault will return.